# Android: Delay before onFinish() in CountDownTimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I was trying to create a simple Tap Counter app but i am getting a noticeable lag at the end before it moves to the onFinish(), giving user a couple of extra taps before stopping the counter.

Here is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tapcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
TextView time;
TextView taps;
Button b;

int flag = 0;
int count = 0, finalTap = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    taps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            if(finalTap==0)
            {
                if(flag==0)
                {
                    beginTimer();
                    flag=1;
                }
                updateCount();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void beginTimer()
{
    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) 
    {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            time.setText("Time: "+millisUntilFinished/1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() 
        {
            time.setText("Timeout!!!");
            finalTap++;
        }
    }.start();  
}

private void updateCount()
{
    taps.setText("Taps: " + Integer.toString(++count));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

on the first how did you run your App? I noticed that when i run an App in Debugmode, the Debugger eats 50% of the performance of my mobile Device. So if you just run your App the onFinish works much faster.

A second point is to detect the timeout manually in the onTick Method an block the taps after some time with a boolean

```
private boolean tapBlock = false;

private void beginTimer()
{
    new CountDownTimer(10100, 1000) 
    {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    {
        if (!tapBlock)
        {
          time.setText("Time: "+millisUntilFinished/1000);
          if (millisUntilFinished<100)
          {
            tapBlock = true;
          }
        }
    }

    public void onFinish() 
    {
        time.setText("Timeout!!!");
        finalTap++;
        tapBlock = false;
    }
    }.start();  
}
```

This is a bit around but its maybe faster and you have to add the "tapBlock" to the update method

Answer (score 0):

There are two factors here:

- first onTick and onFinish will not happen at exact time - in your example millisUntilFinished parameter will have values like 8995 etc up to 990.
- second calculation in your onTick method uses integer division - remainder is cut off. So continuing our example on the last call 990/1000 will be 0, but onFinish will be called only about 1000ms later.